# Asp.net String.Length counting return as 2 chars?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

Im counting characters of a message from a textbox that will be sent as an sms,
I've noticed that txtBody.Text.Length is counting more characters for returns, understand i want to keep the formatting of a newline but .net is counting 2 characters for this is there any way to keep the new line but get the counter to be accurate or is a return itself 2 characters ???

Comment: Be careful ignoring the count of new-line characters if you keep them in the SMS message - they will still count towards the 168 characters in the SMS

Comment: @Neil 168? I know encoding scenarios that offer 160, 140, 70 (counting surrogates as one each) and 155chars per single message. When can you get 168?

Comment: @Jon My mistake - its 160 characters. Don't know where I got 168 from either. Add a unit test for that.

Comment: LOL. That said, it's the 140, 70 and 155char cases that really need the unit test in the actual code, though the 155 is so operator-dependant as to perhaps be best ignored.

Comment: @neil, its not that im not counting the newline its that i dont want to count Environment.Newline which is 2 characters for what should be one("\n") on the sms so String.length becomes unfit for purpose to evaluate if you don't modify the string first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textbox input will give you `Environment.Newline` whenever the user has input a new line (barring some relatively strange copy-pasting), which on windows is the same as `"\u000D\u000A"` (or the shorter `"\r\n"` which means the same thing).

For SMS sending you only really need to use U+000A.

Hence you can simply do `msg.Replace("\r\n", "\n")` before you do any further work. Not only will you get the Length result you want, but you cut down on wasted characters that SMSs don't need, and every char counts when it comes to SMS, hnce hrribl nnsens lik dis!

You might as well normalise further to `msg.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace('\r', '\n\')` to make more sense out of strange copy-pasted data with non-Windows-normal line-breaks (does happen in some scenarios).

Note that you're going to have more complications if you can't stay within the GSM 7-bit alphabet, though if you can't stay within the 8-bit either, then at least your complications will match between .NET and SMS; since .NET uses UTF-16 and SMS does when other encodings don't suffice, they treat surrogates the same as far as length goes.

Comment: thanks this answered me fully. The system wont allow copying from other sources so it could be fine with  msg.Replace("\r\n", "\n").. thanks

Comment: \r wouldn't do any harm anyway, it can just be convenient to normalise when it comes to other tasks.

Answer (score 7):

The newline in windows is indeed 2 characters - `CrLf` - ASCII 13 followed by ASCII 10.

You can simply decrement 2 from the returned `Length`, or get a count of all `Environment.NewLine`, double that by 2 and decrement from the `Length`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string msg = "bla bla etc.\r\nSome more bla";
int length = msg.Replace("\r\n","").Length;
```